# When 马 is used as the left component (e.g. in 骑), does the 一 héng stroke change to ㇀ tí?

Tags: characters, simplified-characters, radicals, character-components, strokes

I am thinking about the 马 character. I know that when you use 土 and 车 on the left in a composed character (like 地，场... and  较，辆 ...) the 3rd stroke in 土， and the 4th in 车 change from 一 héng to ㇀ tí.

My question is: does that change also apply to the 马 character when used as the left component, as in e.g. 骑?

Is there any website where the strokes are identified correctly in accordance with Chinese standards?

edited :  I finally found a website that gives the nature of strokes : https://www.archchinese.com/chinese_english_dictionary.html?find=%E9%A1%B9

Answer (score 4):

According to [《通用规范汉字表》](http://www.moe.gov.cn/publicfiles/business/htmlfiles/moe/cmsmedia/other/2013/7/other98742.zip)(*"General Standard Chinese Character Table"*), "左部件或左上部件末笔为横的，应该变形为提"(The end stroke of the left part or the upper left part is horizontal character stroke(横), it should be changed upwards character stroke(提)). "骑" meets this condition. "马" is its lest part, the last stroke is horizontal character stroke. Other examples: 蛩, 柴, 鹭, 盐, 瞽.

Also, 左右都有其他构字单位的部件，因处在相对左侧的位置，其末笔为横的，也应变为提(if there are components of other character-forming units on the left and right, due to it's on the relatively left side, the last stroke is horizontal character stroke, so they should also be changed upwards character stroke, such as "鸿, 潋, 鼓, 街, 御"

Answer (score 1):

When 马 is used on the left, the 横 also changes to 提.

[zdic](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E9%AA%91) has animations for stroke order.

Comment: Thanks for the info on 马, I also know that this is valid for 手 ， when used in its 扌 form, also on the left. Unfortunately zdic does not indicate the nature of the lines in its animation :-(         modified: the animation for the character 骉 does not exist on zdic, the drawing is interesting, it seems that the 马 lower left is also concerned, there may be a calligraphic rule ? that helps to continue writing when 横 is changed to 提